# Как обработать данную ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существует код:

```
with open ('Names.txt', 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
     a = list(f) 
     print (a)
     try:
       if a.index("Контейнер 2\n") == 0:
           import os
           os.startfile("C:\Python27\BUY\One.py")
           print("Okey")
        else :
           print ("Не купил")
      except KeyError as e:
           print ("Отсутствует значение", e)
```

Суть которого, нумеровать строки, и при определенных строках запускать файлы. Но иногда в файле .txt, отсутствует нужное название строки (Контейнер 2), и тогда выдает ошибку отсутствия, я попытался обработать ошибку, но ничего не помогает. Как мне можно обработать ошибку? Спасибо.

Comment: *выдает ошибку отсутствия* - это не ошибка. Приводите то, что пишет Вам интерпретатор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    except ValueError as e:
        print ("Отсутствует значение", e)
```